# set new key for each dict in list, based on existing key

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

say I have:

```
[ {a: 'a'}, {a: 'b'}]
```

and I want:

```
[ {a: 'a', b: 'ab'}, {a: 'b', b: 'bb'}]
```

how would I do this in Ansible? Was hoping it would be something like

```
- set_fact:
    result: "{{ input | map('combine', dict(b=item.a + 'b')) | list }}"
```

but I don't know how to access `item` in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a "one liner" in jinja doesn't work, or is so terse that no one else can read it, then it's likely not a good idea

```
- set_fact:
    # we are cloning the input dicts for mutation
    result: >-
      {%- set output = [] -%}
      {%- for d in input: -%}
      {%-   set d2 = dict(d) -%}
      {%-   set _ = d2.update({"b": d2["a"] + "b"}) -%}
      {%-   set _ = output.append(d2) -%}
      {%- endfor -%}
      {{- output -}}
```